# Vector fields of a nonlinear second order system on the boundary of a hyperbola

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, dynamical-systems, nonlinear-system, tangent-line

Consider the second order system

$$\dot{x}_{1}=\dfrac{-6x_1}{u^2}+2x_2 =f_1(x_1,x_2),~\dot{x}_{2}=\dfrac{-2(x_1+x_2)}{u^2}=f_2(x_1,x_2)$$

where $u=1+x^2_1$. Consider the hyperbola $x_2=\dfrac{2}{x_1-\sqrt{2}}$. Show, by investigating the vector field on the boundary of this hyperbola, that trajectories to the right of the branch in the first quadrant cannot cross that branch. I found this question in Exercise problem 4.8 of the book "Nonlinear Systems" by H. K. Khalil.

I first computed $\dfrac{f_2}{f_1}$ and $\dfrac{dx_2}{dx_1}$ at the hyperbola boundary $x_2=\dfrac{2}{x_1-\sqrt{2}}$.

$$\dfrac{f_2}{f_1}|_{x_2=\dfrac{2}{x_1-\sqrt{2}}}=\dfrac{-2x^2_{1}+2\sqrt{2}x_1-4}{2x^2_{1}+6\sqrt{2}x_1+4x^4_{1}+4}.$$

I was looking for some suggestions to approach this problem from here on. Any assistance in greatly appreciated.

Comment: How about taking the dot product between a tangent vector to the hyperbola and the vector field restricted to the hyperbola?

Comment: Thank you. If the dot product is positive, then the vector field on the hyperbola boundary will point outward. When the dot product is zero the vector field will be along the tangential direction on hyperbola boundary and when negative, the vector field will point inward. Therefore, in this case I am supposed to show that the dot product of these two vectors on hyperbola boundary is positive. Is that correct?

Comment: non-negative, but yes :) it looks to me that that would be a way to show what is being asked

Comment: Thank you very much.